# Changing image with button not working

Tags: jquery

The code works when I simply run it with `changeImage(newsrc);` but not when I link it to a button. Do you know why?

```
function changeImage(x) {
  $("#main").attr("src",x);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xvdc8ado/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your onclick attributes use of quotes are not proper

```
<button onclick="changeImage('https://www.google.com/logos/2013/doodle_4_google_2013_-_greece_winner-1735005-hp.jpg')">Click me</button>
```

```js
function changeImage(x) {
  $("#main").attr("src", x);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="main" src="http://images.forbes.com/media/lists/companies/google_416x416.jpg">
<button onclick="changeImage('https://www.google.com/logos/2013/doodle_4_google_2013_-_greece_winner-1735005-hp.jpg')">Click me</button>
```

Note: In the jsfiddle since you are making inline method calls, the script should be added to body/head(2nd dropdown in the left panel) else the function will be created in a closure so won't available in the global scope for the inline invocation to work